# Change value in cell based on partial string match from list plus extra condition

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following macro in excel to change the value in a column from "0" to "1" if a cell in the same row has a partial string match to a list of partial strings.

Example of tables in excel:

| Item Number | Description | On Sale |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Apple | 1 |
| 456 | Orange (Sale) | 1 |
| 456 | Orange | 0 |
| 789 | Banana | 1 |

| Items on Sale |
| --- |
| Apple |
| Banana |
| Sale |

I would like to add an extra condition so that is a special number exists in the row, "Sale" must be present in the description for the item to be listed as a "1".

Example of tables in excel:

| Item Number | Special Number | Description | On Sale |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 |  | Apple | 1 |
| 456 | 111 | Special Apple | 0 |
| 789 |  | Orange | 0 |
| 010 | 222 | Special Orange (Sale) | 1 |
| 011 |  | Banana | 1 |

| Items on Sale |
| --- |
| Apple |
| Banana |
| Sale |

Below is the macro I am currently using:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ChangeBool()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim arrData, arrDataF, rngData As Range, rngDataF As Range
Set rngData = ActiveSheet.Range("B2").CurrentRegion
Set rngDataF = ActiveSheet.Range("F2").CurrentRegion
arrData = rngData.Value
arrDataF = rngDataF.Value
For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
    arrData(i, 3) = 0
    For j = LBound(arrDataF) + 1 To UBound(arrDataF)
        If InStr(1, arrData(i, 2), arrDataF(j, 1), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            arrData(i, 3) = 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i
rngData.Value = arrData
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you think the last cell of `Items on sale` is wrong? `Sale` is not a item. Why is  the item `010` marked as `1`?

Comment: @taller you answered this in your version of the code.  Sale is a keyword that negates all other conditions not being met.  "Special Orange" is not a sale item unless "Sale" is found in the description.  If Special Orange does not have "Sale" associated with it, it is not on sale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Add a `If` clause to check `Special Number` and `Sale`
- Assuming the table starts from row 2 as your previous post

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ChangeBool()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim arrData, arrDataF, rngData As Range, rngDataF As Range
    Const KEYWORD = "Sale"
    Set rngData = ActiveSheet.Range("A2").CurrentRegion
    Set rngDataF = ActiveSheet.Range("F2").CurrentRegion
    arrData = rngData.Value
    arrDataF = rngDataF.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        arrData(i, 4) = 0
        For j = LBound(arrDataF) + 1 To UBound(arrDataF)
            If InStr(1, arrData(i, 3), arrDataF(j, 1), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                If Len(arrData(i, 2)) = 0 Or (Len(arrData(i, 2)) > 0 And InStr(1, arrData(i, 3), KEYWORD, vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
                    arrData(i, 4) = 1
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    rngData.Value = arrData
End Sub
```

Note: Testing data (the last one in `Items on Sale`) is different with your post.

[image]

---

Update:

- Col index is defined as consts, it is easy to maintain if your table layout is changed in future.

```vb
Sub ChangeBool()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim arrData, arrKeyWord, rngData As Range, rngDataF As Range
    Const KEYWORD = "Sale"
    ' Modify as needed
    Const SPE_NUM_COL = 3   'Col C
    Const DES_COL = 11      ' Col K
    Const ONSALE_COL = 15   ' Col O
    Set rngData = ActiveSheet.Range("A2").CurrentRegion
    ' Assume Items on Sale is on Col Q
    Set rngDataF = ActiveSheet.Range("Q2").CurrentRegion
    arrData = rngData.Value
    arrKeyWord = rngDataF.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        arrData(i, ONSALE_COL) = 0
        For j = LBound(arrKeyWord) + 1 To UBound(arrKeyWord)
            If InStr(1, arrData(i, DES_COL), arrKeyWord(j, 1), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                If Len(arrData(i, SPE_NUM_COL)) = 0 Or (Len(arrData(i, SPE_NUM_COL)) > 0 And InStr(1, arrData(i, DES_COL), KEYWORD, vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
                    arrData(i, ONSALE_COL) = 1
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    rngData.Value = arrData
End Sub
```

Comment: What would I edit to change where columns A-D are located on this sheet?  For instance column B shown above should be column C on my actual sheet, column C should be column K on my actual sheet, and column D shown above should be column O on my actual sheet.

Comment: Where is `items on sale` ( col F )?

Comment: I've updated the code. Pls test it.

Comment: "items on sale" are actually located at "Sheets("Sheet2").range("SaleList")"  but I've already changed that.

Comment: Tested and confirmed working! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Extend the If statement like this: (j = 4 is the row number where Sale word is.)

```
Option Explicit
Sub ChangeBool()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim arrData, arrDataF, rngData As Range, rngDataF As Range
Set rngData = ActiveSheet.Range("B2").CurrentRegion
Set rngDataF = ActiveSheet.Range("F2").CurrentRegion
arrData = rngData.Value
arrDataF = rngDataF.Value
For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
    arrData(i, 4) = 0
    For j = LBound(arrDataF) + 1 To UBound(arrDataF)
        If (InStr(1, arrData(i, 3), arrDataF(j, 1), vbTextCompare) > 0 And IsEmpty(arrData(i, 2))) Or _
        (InStr(1, arrData(i, 3), arrDataF(j, 1), vbTextCompare) > 0 And Not IsEmpty(arrData(i, 2)) And j = 4) Then
            arrData(i, 4) = 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i
rngData.Value = arrData
End Sub
```